# How to configure Apache to act as an SSL proxy to an application server?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, ssl, proxy, https

I have one physical server that runs:

- an Apache (httpd) server
- another web server (let's say Tomcat for sake of argument) on port 1234

Can I configure the Apache server to act as a proxy for SSL traffic, while keeping the application server blissfully unaware of SSL?

What I imagine is:

- Traffic to http://myserevr.com/app is redirected to https://myserver.com/app
- Traffic to https://myserver.com/app is proxied to the application server.
- My SSL certificate is only installed on the Apache server, not on the Application server
- Other traffic to the Apache server (http://myserver.com/anotherapp) is served directly from the Apache server

What's the best setup to achieve this? (On Ubuntu, if that matters)

Comment: If you have the option of replacing apache, take a look at nginx which is a lot easier to configure for this

Comment: @hafichuk - is Apache really that hard to configure for this use case?

Answer (score 2):

If Tomcat runs on the standart ports (8080 - HTTP, 8009 - AJP) add this to yours Apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    .......
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia On

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location /app>
        ProxyPass        ajp://localhost:8009/app
        ProxyPassReverse ajp://localhost:8009/app
    </Location>

    #<Location /app>
    #    ProxyPass        http://localhost:8080/app
    #    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/app
    #</Location>

    <Location "/app/WEB-INF/">
        deny from all
    </Location>    
   ..........
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ...........
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/app$  https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
   ...........
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) for Apache, and how to use it in 'reverse proxy' mode.